# How do I delete a single call log entry from my android call register programmatically

Tags: android

I need to delete a single call entry from the call register when the user clicks on `clear this call`.

I managed to delete all call entries of a number while user clicks on `clear all calls` for this number.

How can I clear a single entry from the call register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume you have a details of that call entry which you want to delete then try like this

```html
try {
             int idOfRowToDelete; // I assume you have this id;
            getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(idOfRowToDelete)), "", null);

                }
             catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.print("Exception here ");
            }
```

Comment: or like  context.getContentResolver().delete(
                            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                            CallLog.Calls._ID + " = ? ",
                            new String[] { String.valueOf(idOfRowToDelete) });

Comment: hi ! thanks for helping me, i have activity A with call log listview and activity B with options to a selected call log item, i want to delete selected entry from activity B

Comment: Thanks for your help !! it solved my problem, i got the id in activity A and passed that to activity B and delete the specific entry by using this id